# Access adds extra decimals when grouping in query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Did not found anything to solve this.

I'm doing some easy things on an Access Database 2007 32 bit.

Got this table:

```
Id_iva  Desde       Hasta       Valor_Iva
2       01/01/2000  31/08/2012  18,00%
4       01/09/2012  31/12/2021  21,00%
5       01/01/2022  31/12/2099  25,00%
```

`Valor_iva` is a numeric field, **single** type. I manually input those numbers, with 2 decimals only (in this case all of them are 0, but it could be something like 18,50% or 20,23% and so on)

If I make a query like this:

```
SELECT T_IVA.Hasta, T_IVA.Valor_Iva FROM T_IVA;
```

It works as expected and it returns exactly the values:

[image]

But If my query is this:

```
SELECT T_IVA.Hasta, Sum(T_IVA.Valor_Iva) AS SumaDeValor_Iva FROM T_IVA GROUP BY T_IVA.Hasta;
```

I get extradecimals in some values.

[image]

Can't understand where those decimals come from.

I've googled about CAST and TRUNCATE but I could not apply those (or I don't know how to).

**WHAT I WANT**: I just want to make a GROUP BY query that does not add those decimals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exact results, then cast to an exact type before doing any operations. Or, even better, use an exact (non-floating point) type in the first place.

It seems your values fit in the `Currency` data type. The `Decimal` data type can be used for larger values with decimals.

```
SELECT T_IVA.Hasta, Sum(CCur(T_IVA.Valor_Iva)) AS SumaDeValor_Iva FROM T_IVA GROUP BY T_IVA.Hasta;
```

Comment: This almost works as desired, but it returns the values as Currency type, and they are percentage type. So I'm getting `0,18 €` and I would like to get `18,00%`.

Comment: Use the format property in the design pane to format it as desired. The currency type indeed has weird default formatting.

Comment: Ok, but now iI'm getting a text/string value so when I try to do mathematical operations with these values, I get Error

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it changing properties of the field in the query editor, and it shows as I wish and it's being recognized as number. Thanks! :)